# Email signature not showing up properly in email

Tags: html, email, mobile, signature

I have created an html signature and it looks good on desktop but on mobile the last image is breaking into a new line when it should be directly next to the social media icons. Is there something I can include in the code to make the table row not break into a new line?

Here is the code:

```html
<style>
    table {border-spacing: 0; width:500px; display:block; line-height:0; }
  #container{width:500px; height:167px}
  </style>


<div id="container">
  <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" bgcolor="#000"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2693031/1.gif" width="500" height="76" style="display:block" alt="Cynthia Larenas Freelance Designer &amp; video artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" bgcolor="#000"><a href="http://www.cynthialarenas.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2693031/2.gif" width="500" height="26" style="display:block"   alt="www.cynthialarenas.com"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" bgcolor="#000">
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/cynthialarenas" target="_blank"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2693031/3.gif" width="57" height="68" style="display:inline" alt="Twitter"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/cynthialarenas" target="_blank"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2693031/4.gif" width="28" height="68" style="display:inline"  alt="instagram"/></a>
        <a href="http://cynthialarenasblog.tumblr.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2693031/5.gif" width="24" height="68" style="display:inline"   alt="tumblr"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.vimeo.com/cynthialarenas" target="_blank"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2693031/6.gif" width="37" height="68" style="display:inline"  alt="vimeo"/></a>
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2693031/7.gif" width="330" style="display:inline" alt=""/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot that how it looks in email received?

Comment: @WordPressMechanic here is the screenshot https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2693031/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-22%20at%206.47.06%20pm.png